# No pending reply: ConsumerRecord

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to use ReplyingKafkaTemplate, and intermittently I keep seeing the message below.

> No pending reply: ConsumerRecord(topic = request-reply-topic,
>   partition = 8, offset = 1, CreateTime = 1544653843269, serialized key
>   size = -1, serialized value size = 1609, headers =
>   RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = kafka_correlationId, value
>   = [-14, 65, 21, -118, 70, -94, 72, 87, -113, -91, 92, 72, -124, -110, -64, -94])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, with correlationId: [-18271255759235816475365319231847350110], perhaps timed out, or using
>   a shared reply topic

It would stem from the code below

```
RequestReplyFuture<K, V, R> future = this.futures.remove(correlationId);
if (future == null) {
  if (this.sharedReplyTopic) {
    if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      this.logger.debug(missingCorrelationLogMessage(record, correlationId));
    }
  }
  else if (this.logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
    this.logger.error(missingCorrelationLogMessage(record, correlationId));
  }
}
```

But happens only intemittently

I have also set the shared replyTopic to false as below and attempted to force a longer timeout

```
ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Object, Object> replyKafkaTemplate = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
        replyKafkaTemplate.setSharedReplyTopic(false);
        replyKafkaTemplate.setReplyTimeout(10000);
        return replyKafkaTemplate;
```

My Container is as below

```
@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

    factory.setBatchListener(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(1000);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(10000L);
    factory.setConcurrency(3);
    factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate());
    return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's intermittent, it's most likely the reply took too long to arrive. The message seems quite clear

> perhaps timed out, or using a shared reply topic

Each client side instance must use it's own reply topic or dedicated partition.

**EDIT**

You get the log if a message is received with a correlation id that does not match the entries currently in this.futures (pending replies). This can only occur under the following circumstances:

1. The request timed out (in which case there will be a corresponding WARN log).
2. The template is stop()ped (in which case this.futures is cleared).
3. An already processed reply is redelivered for some reason (shouldn't happen).
4. The reply is received before the key is added to this.futures (can't happen since it's inserted before send()ing the record).
5. The server side sends 2 or more replies for the same request.
6. Some other application is sending data to the same reply topic. If you can reproduce it with DEBUG logging, it would help because then we log the correlation key on the send as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response from my logs the timeout happens too soon from my logs I see the consumer receiving the request at <b>2018-12-13 02:37:46,713| INFO  | org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 and the timeout just a few milliseconds later <b>2018-12-13 02:37:46,839| ERROR | replyContainer-C-1             | IPC | ReplyingKafkaTemplate          -309 |No pending reply: ConsumerRecord

Comment: `sharedReplyTopic` should be `true` if you have multiple client instances; it is false by default; setting it true changes the error log to a debug log. I see you have a listener container on the server side; what is the listener? It is impossible to get this error unless some message with an unrecognized correlation id header value is received by the template.

Comment: Right now I have one client instance so I guess its already on the error log. When you say unrecognized do you mean corrupted as it is logged as below `with correlationId: [-25828241019201938464047331559992730192], perhaps timed out, or using a shared reply topic`

Comment: Thanks Gary issue was #2 I was using the incorrect  ReplyTemplate changed my container config to `factory.setReplyTemplate(replyKafkaTemplate(producerFactory(), replyContainer(consumerFactory())));` and the error is gone not sure if you need to modify your answer, I am very new to this!

Comment: I moved my last 2 comments to the answer; you should not be using a replying template on the server side at all. The replying template is a client-side artifact for request/reply scenarios. On the server side you only use a simple `KafkaTemplate` in the factory's `replyTemplate` property. The container receives the request and uses the template to send the reply.

Comment: Interesting because without that config the future was null and futures size 0

Comment: @GaryRussell Could you please check the possibility of this as if the same groupID was given to multiple server and request was performed on node 1 ,as both node was having same groupid for the replay topic the replay topic will be send message to either one of the node ,if it is send the response to replay topic and subscribed to node 2 then also this message will be shown as there is no pending thread for the response to serve.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on 2+ year old answers. If you are using the same group id on the reply topic, you must specify a reply partition so that the reply goes back to the right instance. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#replying-template). `>If you have multiple client instances and you do not configure them as discussed in the preceding paragraph, each instance needs a dedicated reply topic. An alternative is to set the KafkaHeaders.REPLY_PARTITION and use a dedicated partition for each instance. ...`

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks, one suggestion if we could configure different groupId for both nodes then it will work right?

Comment: It will "work" but both servers will process the request, which may not be what you want. Read the documentation I pointed you too.

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed using on the consumer the attribute @Header (KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID)

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.model}")
@SendTo("replymodeltopic")
@Override
public Model receive(ConsumerRecord<String, model> record, @Header(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) byte[] correlation) { 
    record.headers().add(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlation);
    return record.value();
}
```

on my configuration i have

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class ReceiverConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${kafka.tunnel.group}")
    private String tunnelGroup;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.json.reply}")
    private String jsonTopicReply;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, tunnelGroup);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Model> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Model.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Model> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Model> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setReplyTemplate(replyTemplate());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Model> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Model> replyTemplate() {
        KafkaTemplate<String, Model> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
        kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic(jsonTopicReply);
        return kafkaTemplate;
    }

}
```